# How to create Sinatra app with page that reloads with new content not cache

Tags: ruby, caching, sinatra, browser-cache

I trying to create a fairly minimal example for templates and teaching.

I create my `app.rb` file

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  "Minimal!__ !_!"
end
```

My Gemfile just has

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rspec'
gem 'thin'
```

I started up Sinatra

```
$ ruby app.rb 
== Sinatra (v2.0.5) has taken the stage on 4567 for development with backup from Thin
Thin web server (v1.7.2 codename Bachmanity)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on localhost:4567, CTRL+C to stop
```

and I can visit the page

[image]

but when I then change the code the page is cached and the new content doesn't show unless i stop and start the server.

I've read the Sinatra documentation but still can't figure it out.

I've tried adding

```
set :sessions, false
```

and

```
   cache_control :off
```

to no avail

Comment: if you wrote the `"Minimal!__ !_!"` into an actual view file (a html or erb template) it would properly reload. However for changes to the Ruby code you need to either restart the server, or use a library such as [rerun](https://github.com/alexch/rerun) or [shotgun](https://github.com/rtomayko/shotgun). The behavior you see is not because of a cache, it's because rack does not automatically reload source code in general

Comment: I like the erb approach however when i tried `text = "MMinimal!__ !_!<%= 'frooYZZYoggy' %>"
  erb text` it didn't reload when i then changed the text within the erb tag

Comment: I mean an actual `.erb` file. It reloads and recompiles the file on every request, meaning refreshing the page will show updates to that file. _Refreshing the page does not cause the `.rb` code to reload though_ and your inline erb code is no exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *were* having problems with the cache you could tell the browser not to cache anything:

```
cache_control :no_cache
```

You might also add Pragma and Expires to the header:

```
headers \
  "Pragma"   => "no-cache",
  "Expires" => "0"
```

and put it all in a `before` filter:

```
before do
  cache_control :no_cache
  headers \
    "Pragma"   => "no-cache",
    "Expires" => "0"
end
```

Or, since you're doing demonstrations, open the browser's inspector and turn off caching. Both Chrome and Firefox have this option.

(OP Adding this) A minimalist version for one call might be just to have

```
  headers "Expires" => "0"
```

within the get in question

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`sinatra-reloader`](http://sinatrarb.com/contrib/reloader)

Based on the example code, your app seems to be of the "classic" type.
Therefore simply load the `reloader` library into your app:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/reloader' if development?

get '/' do
  "Minimal!__ !_!"
end
```

Since you're using a Gemfile, ensure that you've the `sinatra-contrib` gem listed as well (and install it via `bundle install`):

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rspec'
gem 'thin'
gem 'sinatra', '~> 2.0`
gem 'sinatra-contrib', '~> 2.0'
```

Otherwise install the gem directly: `gem install sinatra-contrib`

Now onwards anytime you start up the server in `'development'` mode and make changes to either your `app.rb` or your `views/index.erb`, the changes will be reflected in your browser with a refresh.